# How to create a blank NS project that uses tns-core-modules 2.5

Tags: nativescript

How can I create a new NS project that uses older non 3.0 core module

I usually create a blank project with:

`tns create test --template tsc`

Comment: as mentioned here (https://docs.nativescript.org/releases/upgrade-instructions), you can update the cli to as `tns update 2.3.0` and then install it `npm install tns-core-modules@version`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you cannot do through command line.

For me the solution was to create a package.json file which contain all element that you need in your app, but at version described here http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=509 - in my case for angular template

For example this is a package.json created by command tns create ...

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~4.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~4.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.1.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~3.0.0"
....
```

copy that to a new folder then change like i.e

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~2.5.2"
....
```

After that execute command npm install inside the folder.

At this point if you have an existing project to downgrade copy only the app folder from the existing project into the new folder; otherwise you can start create manually app folder and start coding your app.

Finally run tns run ios or android and you're done :)

Sorry for the long answer but it's not easy to explain from keyboard